# How can I calculate the volt-second balance of a boost converter with 2 outputs?

Tags: circuit-analysis, boost

Say I have a boost converter, but it has two outputs and three states.
On interval it charges up the inductor, the next interval it charges one output, and the next interval it charges the other output.

In below schematic I connected the load between the two channels, but normally the output of a boost converter does not depend on the load. Alternatively consider two loads to ground, or no load at all.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDILx2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Looking at the [Wikipedia section about boost converter operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter#Continuous_mode), they derive the usual 1/(1-D) from the fact that during steady-state the total variation of the inductor current is zero.

Let D be the duty cycle from the inductor to ground and k(1-D) and (1-k)(1-D) the duty cycles to the two outputs.

\begin{align}
\Delta I_{L,on}=&\frac{1}{L}\int_0^{DT} V_{in} d\tau\\
\Delta I_{L,on}=&\frac{DT}{L}V_{in}\\
\Delta I_{L,cross}=&\frac{1}{L}\int_{DT}^{(D+k(1-D))T} V_{in} - V_{out,2} d\tau\\
\Delta I_{L,cross}=&\frac{T}{L}k(1-D)(V_{in} - V_{out,2})\\
\Delta I_{L,fwd}=&\frac{1}{L}\int_{(D+k(1-D))T}^{T} V_{in} - V_{out,1} d\tau\\
\Delta I_{L,fwd}=&\frac{T}{L}(1-D-k(1-D))(V_{in} - V_{out,1})\\
0=&\Delta I_{L,on}+\Delta I_{L,cross}+\Delta I_{L,fwd}\\
%0=&D V_{in} + k(1-D)(V_{in} - V_{out,2}) + (1-D-k(1-D))(V_{in} - V_{out,1})\\
0=&V_{in}-k(1-D)V_{out,2}-(1-D-k(1-D))V_{out,1}\\
\end{align}

This is an equation with two unknowns, suggesting that except for k=1 or k=0, there are many possible voltages that result in a steady inductor current, but of course the real world has only one voltage. What is missing?

Simulation in LTspice shows that the output on both ends is approximately 1/(1-D) and the voltage across the resistor scales with the current ripple. This is intuitively kind of expected, but the math doesn't work out.

[edit]
I tried a simulation with two loads to ground. Very much CCM, pretty much independant of any component values. Still no way to analyse it. I also cheated a bit with the diodes.
[image]

Comment: As you have no ground path from either output, unless you have modified the driver topology for two-quadrant operation (i.e. you have states with both M1 and either M2 or M3 conducting) I wouldn't expect standard approaches to work.

Comment: The duty cycle only defines the output voltage when operating in continuous inductor current conduction mode (CCM). In DCM the output voltage is load dependent.

Comment: M2 and M3 do nothing as their bulk diodes are conducting in clockwise loop direction.

Comment: I made it with ideal switches. With 2 loads to ground it does sort of work.